# How to identify top bar item package

Tags: top-bar, tiling

### Task

Identifying the top bar item shown in the screenshot below.

### Background

It appears to be some sort of pseudo tiling manager (i.e. it tiles things, but only until you drag the windows from their locations). When the top bar item is clicked, it produces the psuedo tiling manager window shown in bottom left of screenshot.

It seems I installed this years ago before switching to Regolith Desktop and forgot about it as the top bar is replaced by a similar but custom bar in Regolith Desktop. Now trying out Pop Shell and the keyboard shortcuts are conflicting, so trying to uninstall this, but having trouble identifying it. Is there a directory/config file that stores what is shown on the top bar? Everything I've searched for always references the Tweaks app for modifying the top bar, but this does not provide any information about this item.

[image]

Let me know if I can provide any other info that may prove useful to id'ing it.

Answer (score 0):

After going through my entire ~/.config directory and 'apt list --installed' I reopened Tweaks only to find it sitting at the bottom of the Extensions tab. It was an extension called gTile.

I'm still happy to award the answer to someone who can tell me how to find these extensions without the Tweaks app installed (i.e. via the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

The source files for top bar apps might be ascertained from /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

The source files of the Gnome extension are in the /home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extension.
.local is a hidden folder, hence use the menu option of the nautilus - show hidden files to view the .local.